# Discord.js Leaderboard Command

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord, discord.js

how to make a leaderboard command with this JSON database?

```
{
    guildId:{
        userId:{
            coin: 1,
            money: 0
        }
        userId:{
            coin: 3,
            money: 0
        }
    }
}
```

I already tried with this code and its working, but I don't know how to show the leaderboard into a message.

```
const coins = require("./Config/coins.json");
        const sorted = [];

        for (let guild in lvl) {
            for (let user in lvl[guild]){
                if(guild === message.guild.id){
                    const levl = lvl[guild][user].allxp;
                    const entry = {[user] : lvl[guild][user]}
                    
                    if (sorted.length === 0) {
                    sorted.push(entry);
                
                    continue;
                    }
                    let i = 0;
                    while (sorted[i] !== undefined && sorted[i][Object.keys(sorted[i])].allxp > levl) {
                    i++;
                    }
                    
                    sorted.splice(i, 0, entry)    
                }
            }
        }
```

The code gives this output,  how to make this into a leaderboard?

```
[
  { '658761055627116604': { xp: 1753, allxp: 6753, level: 5 } },
  { '730453900842500148': { xp: 41, allxp: 3041, level: 4 } },
  { '736140177130520616': { xp: 126, allxp: 626, level: 2 } },
  { '722764152967266354': { xp: 447, allxp: 447, level: 1 } },
  { '501982335076532224': { xp: 135, allxp: 135, level: 1 } },
  { '235088799074484224': { xp: 61, allxp: 61, level: 1 } },
  { '705771638695657483': { xp: 29, allxp: 29, level: 1 } },
  { '736482631268565033': { xp: 17, allxp: 17, level: 1 } },
  { '505316479064080384': { xp: 28, allxp: 0, level: 2 } }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can push all the users on an Array then use the **sort** on that array, and this is going to give you all the users from the Major to Minor level.

This is a function that I use on my bot:

```
sortServerRanks: function (usersRank, guilds, message, StateManager) {
const arrayMembers = guilds.get(message.guild.id).Member;
for (let index = 0; index < arrayMembers.length; index++) {
  usersRank.push(arrayMembers[index].memberXP);
}
usersRank.sort((a, b) => b - a);
for (let i = 0; i < usersRank.length; i++) {
  for (let index = 0; index < arrayMembers.length; index++) {
    if (parseInt(arrayMembers[index].memberXP) === parseInt(usersRank[i])) {
      arrayMembers[index].serverRank = i + 1;
      updateGuildServerRank(
        arrayMembers[index].guildID,
        arrayMembers[index].memberID,
        i + 1
      );
      StateManager.emit(
        "updateServerRank",
        arrayMembers[index].guildID,
        arrayMembers[index].memberID,
        arrayMembers[index].serverRank,
        i + 1
      );
    }
  }
}
```

}

The only piece of code that you need is this:

```
for (let index = 0; index < arrayMembers.length; index++) {
  usersRank.push(arrayMembers[index].memberXP);
}
usersRank.sort((a, b) => b - a);
```

Is a ***for*** that take all the members *xp* from your **.json** file and then push them on a local array, then I use the sort to organize from Major to Minor.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to use [Message Embeds](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#embed-preview), where the fields are the leaderboard entries.

```
const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#0099ff')
    .setTitle('Some title')
    .setDescription('Some description here')
    .addFields(
        { name: user, value: xp/level },
        { name: user, value: xp/level },
        { name: user, value: xp/level },
        { name: user, value: xp/level },
    )

channel.send(exampleEmbed);
```

Answer (score 0):

I made quickly a piece of code, with my own .json file, maybe this can help you.

```
  let usersLength = Object.keys(allUsers).length;
  let numberID = 0;
  var usersArray = [];
  var serverUsersArray = [];

  for (let index = 0; index < usersLength; index++) {
    //XP and levels
    if (!xp[allUsers[index].id]) {
      xp[allUsers[index].id] = {
        xp: 0,
        level: 1,
        bost: 1,
        xprol: 0,
        levelrol: 1,
        biography: "none",
        age: 1,
        rank: 0,
        rankserver: 0,
        respect: 0,
        work: "none",
        relation: "Soltero/a",
      };
    }
    serverUsersArray.push(xp[allUsers[index].id].xp);
    usersArray.push(xp[allUsers[index].id].xprol);
  }
  serverUsersArray.sort((a, b) => b - a);
  usersArray.sort((a, b) => b - a);
  numberID = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(usersArray).length; i++) {
    for (let index = 0; index < usersLength; index++) {
      if (xp[allUsers[index].id].xprol === usersArray[i]) {
        xp[allUsers[index].id].rank = i + 1;
      }
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(serverUsersArray).length; i++) {
    for (let index = 0; index < usersLength; index++) {
      if (xp[allUsers[index].id].xp === serverUsersArray[i]) {
        xp[allUsers[index].id].rankserver = i + 1;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: "allUsers" is the import of the .json file..

´const allUsers = require("../../database/users/users.json");´

Comment: in this file is there a userId? if there is, is it only userId? Is there anything else besides userid?

Comment: Well I use the .json File like this:

'{
  "0": {
    "id": "677725104712712202",
    "admin": "no",
    "mod": "no",
    "inmortal": "no"
  } '

Comment: I use this file like a giant Array Map, Where the ID and the perms of each member are save.

Comment: okay thanks, and what is the "levelrol" and "xprol"? is it mean allxp?

Comment: Well, is another function that my bot has where evaluate the XP from a Linked Videogame (Multi Theft Auto) is a Roleplay server, and the bot takes the commands and time that the user expends on the Server.